# Prevent POST request

Tags: php, linux, apache, http-post

I have a sever with Linux and Apache latest version. I noticed that if I send a POST with data to any address on the site this is accepted even if there is not a specific PHP script that can handle it. I think it's normal. But how can I prevent this? I know that some sites (Ebay) complete the post before returning an error (imagine if the post includes a large file, server bandwidth consumption is guaranteed).
How can you prevent a POST from running upstream of a php script or any other script? Do you have to work on the Apache server or in the .htaccess?

Comment: No. you can add input field validations to check if form is filled. if you need to check if dorm's action php script exists before submit, you can do that with either php or ajax. use php *$filename = "yourfile.php file path";
    if (file_exists($filename)) { $actionurl="$filename" } else{$actionurl = "#"} then use $actionurl in form's action="$actionurl"*

Comment: Maybe you can use the <limit>Directive in your apache config as suggested here https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56778/201311

Comment: Vishwa.Yes, I know, but php does not exist, not even a script actually exists, the directory is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set your response headers to tell your browser what your end point accepts...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'); // just exclude the POST method
```

I had gotten this from the CORS specifications. If it doesn't work then it's probably because this header has to be in response to an OPTIONS request instead.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to block the request before it reaches PHP. I'm not sure about the `header()` method, but restricting access from .htaccess seems a safer option.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

Comment: If I adopted this method would I prevent the entire site from accepting POST? How can I accept posts only if I have a script that can handle them?

Comment: This depends on your project structure and its complexity. You could add `RewriteCond` for each of the pages that can process POST requests. I'm not sure how to help here. You might also want to give a thought as to why you want to block POSTs. You mentioned bandwidth consumption, but I don't think this might be an issue, or better yet - I don't think denying POSTs is a solution. Whoever wants to eat up your bandwidth can do so with GET just as easily or just target the links that support POST.

Comment: Yes, my answer would block POST requests for the entire website. You have to use customise the answer to suit your needs. Maybe put all "non-POST" scripts into a folder and add the .htaccess rule inside that particular folder?

Comment: Each site directory then must have its .htacces with the appropriate rules and still have other rules in the PHP script that allow or deny any operations. Thank you. I think it's the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried but the post is still executed even if an error is returned. I'm posting it from an application written in Delphi that uses the Indy idHttp component.